# extract multiples same string from a string

Tags: java, string

I need to split a String by a specific `String` which can be placed anywhere (there can be multiple occurences of this string at same time) and reconstruct the entire string by adding extracts into something like a `StringBuffer`. The case of the specific String to seek must be insensitive

For example:

```
String targeted =  "test" ;
String plainString ="azertytestqwerty";

//desired outcome

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("azerty");
sb.append("test");
sb.append("qwerty");

--------------------------

String targeted =  "test" ;
String plainString ="a.test";

//desired outcome

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("a.");
sb.append("test");

--------------------------

String targeted =  "test" ;
String plainString ="test mlm";

//desired outcome

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("test");
sb.append("mlm");

--------------------------

String targeted =  "test" ;
String plainString ="aaatestzzztest";

//desired outcome

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("aaa");
sb.append("test");
sb.append("zzz");
sb.append("test");
```

Any simple way to do this?

I think I need to use a regex like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*"+targeted +".*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if (matcher.find())
{
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

But then I don't know how to extract the strings and add them in same order

The reason why I do this it's because the `plainString` will be added into a Excel cell using POI but I need to add font color for the targeted string.

Example:

```
XSSFRichTextString richString = new XSSFRichTextString();
richString.append("azerty");
richString.append("test", highlightFont);
richString.append("qwerty");
cell.setCellValue(richString);
```

Thank you very much

Comment: what is the goal of adding to a StringBuffer like this?
If you're "reconstructing the entire string", whats wrong with just doing 

`StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(plainString);`

Comment: @Dustin Ryan-Roepsch . Post edited with more precisions .  Thank you very much :)

Comment: Gotcha! That makes much more sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the method, you can try any combination.

```
public String extractMultiples(String plainString, String targeted) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    // split covers all occurrences in the beginning;empty element, and in
    // the middle
    String[] result = plainString.split(targeted);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        sb.append(result[i]);
        if (i < result.length - 1)// not the last one
            sb.append(targeted);
    }

    // in the end
    if (plainString.endsWith(targeted))
        sb.append(targeted);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: hello thank you very much for your answer but the targeted string can be anywhere into the String so it's more complicated :/. See my updated question please . Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you man , you really helped me a lot . I don't know how to thank you. i was struggling hard . Still one more case , when the plainString is composed with only the targetedString . The buffer will add the targetedString 2 times

Comment: @ulquiorra In fact it will not, because the result is empty, it will add it once in the end section, I have just tested that. hh and the best way to say thank you is to vote the answer and call it right :), good luck.

Comment: Yes , indeed , i just forgot to include case sensitive management . Now it works ! . Thank you very much man :)

Answer (score 2):

**Pattern** and **Matcher** are maybe a little bit too much...

just do a split on the word and then make a for loop over the resulting array...

## Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String targeted = "test";
    String plainString = "azertytestqwerty";
    String[] result = plainString.split(targeted);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        sb.append(result[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: and if you want to do something special with the target you would just check if result[i].equals(target);

Comment: @ΦXoce 웃 Пepeúpa , hello thank you very much for your answer but the targeted string can be anywhere into the String so it's more complicated :/.  I think i need some good combinations between ``indexof`` and ``substring`` . See my updated question please . Thanks :)